# Align two lists and do action on aligned and miss-aligned objects

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I try to find a way to align two lists of objects (sorted by it's value) and by comparing it's value , do a action if objects are aligned in both lists and another action if not. For example kids with he's name and age, and use age value to align them.

To make the example simple, try with just two sorted list of integer values:

```
a = (1,2,3,6,7,11,13)
b = (2,3,4,6,7,9)
```

I want to align them like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 01 | 02 | 03 | xx | 06 | 07 | xx | 11 | 13 |
+----+         +----+         +----+----+----+
| xx | 02 | 03 | 04 | 06 | 07 | 09 | xx | xx |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

To do a action on aligned value (append it to a list1 for example):

```
list1 = [2,3,6,7]
```

And doing action on miss-aligned value (append it to a list2 for example):

```
list2 = [1,4,9,11,13]
```

or just doing a print if aligned or not:

```
1 = miss-aligned
2 = aligned
3 = aligned
4 = miss-aligned
6 = aligned
7 = aligned
9 = miss-aligned
11 = miss-aligned
13 = miss-aligned
```

I try this way but ...

```
a = (1,2,3,6,7,11,13)
b = (2,3,4,6,7,9)
list1 = []
list2 = []

# find sames and list a different value
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if x == y:
            list1.append(x)
            print(x," = aligned")
            break
        if y == b[-1]:
            print(x," = miss-aligned")
            list2.append(x)

# find list b different value
for y in b:
    for x in a:
        if x == y:
            break
        if x == a[-1]:
            print(y," = miss-aligned")
            list2.append(y)

print('Same:',list1)
print('Different:',list2)
```

... I get this non-desired ouput (not doing action in good order for 4 and 9):

```
1  = miss-aligned
2  = aligned
3  = aligned
6  = aligned
7  = aligned
11  = miss-aligned
13  = miss-aligned
4  = miss-aligned
9  = miss-aligned
Same: [2, 3, 6, 7]
Different: [1, 11, 13, 4, 9]
```

I try many others way without success.

*edit: No duplicate of value in the same list

Comment: Can there be duplicates in each list? And also in your case only `6` is aligned. You need to better define what you mean by saying **align**, maybe you mean *is present in both lists*?

Comment: no duplicate in the same list. The better way I find to define "aligned" is the little draw I did in ascii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lists are sorted you can do something like this:

```
def same_diff(a, b):
    sames = []
    diffs = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            sames.append(a[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif a[i] > b[j]:
            diffs.append(b[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            diffs.append(a[i])
            i += 1
    diffs += a[i:]
    diffs += b[j:]
    return sames, diffs

a = (1,2,3,6,7,11,13)
b = (2,3,4,6,7,9)

same_diff(a, b)
# ([2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 4, 9, 11, 13])
```

---

If you are doing something with the values instead of appending the remaining values you can loop over them:

```
def same_diff(a, b):
    sames = []
    diffs = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            print 'aligned', a[i]
            sames.append(a[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif a[i] > b[j]:
            print 'miss-aligned', b[j]
            diffs.append(b[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            print 'miss-aligned', a[i]
            diffs.append(a[i])
            i += 1
    while i < len(a):
        print 'miss-aligned', a[i]
        diffs.append(a[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(b):
        print 'miss-aligned', b[j]
        diffs.append(b[j])
        j += 1
    return sames, diffs
```

Would result in:

```
same_diff(a, b)

miss-aligned 1
aligned 2
aligned 3
miss-aligned 4
aligned 6
aligned 7
miss-aligned 9
miss-aligned 11
miss-aligned 13
# ([2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 4, 9, 11, 13])
```

Comment: exactly what I'm searching for ! I already try something like you but I'm get lost and very messy with many "if condition" and never get a good result. I understand it now and more clear to me ( the second code is more what I want to do ). Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get:

- the elements that are present in both lists
- the elements that are present only in one of the lists

`set` will come handy:

```
a_set = set(a)
b_set = set(b)

same = sorted(a_set.intersection(b_set))
different = sorted(a_set.symmetric_difference(b_set))

print(same)
print(different)
```

...you will get:

```
[2, 3, 6, 7]
[1, 4, 9, 11, 13]
```

If it does matter in which list the mis-alignment happens you can do a simple subtraction:

```
mis_aligned_a = b - a  # [9, 4]
mis_aligned_b = a - b  # [1, 11, 13]
```

Comment: Yes but the result look like the code I did : Action applied on aligned value is in good order but not on miss-aligned value (4 and 9 at the end). And I don't just want to make two list of same and different elements , but doing a action if is same or not in good order ( like the "print" I did of it for example ).

Comment: What about sorting? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's give the good result but Dting find a solution that fit more my needs. It's allow inserting code if value is aligned or not like I describes. But thanks a lot for your help to find a solution. Really appreciated !